# Existence of faithful normal state

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Does there always exist faithful normal state on center of von Neumann algebra?

Further, in type II$_{1}$ von Neumann  algebras are tracial states coming from the center valued trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question is the same as asking if every abelian von Neumann algebra has a faithful normal state. The answer is easily no, by taking for instance the example in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2853865/22857).

As for all tracial states coming from the center-valued trace, it is not entirely clear to me what you mean. If you have 
$$
M=\bigoplus_n A_n\otimes N_n,
$$
where $A_n$ are abelian and $N_n$ are II$_1$-factors, the center-valued trace is induced by 
$$
\Phi(\bigoplus_n a_n\otimes x_n)=\bigoplus_n a_n\otimes 1. 
$$
Tracial states are obtained by taking $f_n\in S(A_n)$ and $\tau_n$ the unique trace on $N_n$, and letting
$$
\phi(\bigoplus_n a_n\otimes x_n)=\sum_n f_n(a_n)\tau(x_n).
$$
I cannot immediately say in what sense $\phi$ "comes" from $\Phi$.

Comment: Meaning is if $\rho$ is a tracial state in von Neumann algebra(factor), does there exist centervalued trace $\phi$ such that $\phi(A)=\rho(A)I$

Comment: The center-valued trace is unique.